# How to view android keystore type

Tags: android, keystore

With which command I can view keystore type using keytool? There is not direct parameter for it.

In list of parameters there is no parameter like -info to view information about keystore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose you need to use parameter -list

```
keytool -list -keystore mykeystore.keystore
```

It will return list of entries and keystore info

```
Keystore type: jks
Keystore provider: SUN
...
```